Data recovery via ADB on a broken phone
I am trying to pull data from my broken phone over ABD. But I keep getting error connect failed .
My phone is in recovery mode as it cant boot , in cmd I have my phone listed with my serial and also says sideload but any command results in failed connection.

Do you use the pre-installed stock recovery ROM or have you unlocked bootloader and installed a custom recovery? because stock recovery only supports adb sideload and has no capability to decrypt user data, thus there is no data access possible.

Stock ROM . So there is no way to recover files from the device
?

If your phone does not boot you can't access your files on a stock device.

depending on how old is the phone, there might be a way. what is the phone model?
